# Seeking algorithm for polygon straightening

Tags: polygon, algorithm, simplify

I have a polygon that looks like this:

[image]

I want to get a result that ideally looks like this:

[image]

The best that I can come up with is a polygon simplification using shapely in Python:

[image]

Which algorithm could deal with this problem?

The polygon files are [here](https://github.com/UralmashFox/polygon).

Comment: Could you share the polygon geometry (WKT string, for instance)? It is hard to make one like that to work on it.

Comment: added link to repo with files

Comment: You could rasterize the polygon onto a coarse grid. That would help create the linearity you seem to want. Then you could smooth that grid with morphological operators (e.g. erode/dilate). I don't have time to implement it and not sure it'd get you what you want. (BTW there's a hole in your brown polygon on the right-most finger that shouldn't be there?)

Comment: no, the hole is not nesessary right now. Thanks, I'll try now

Comment: ArcGIS "Simplify Building" generates similar output that you desire. I couldn't find a solution in QGIS years ago. So I had to use the tool in ArcGIS. -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocqEG.png